# Reading binary from pickle file

Tags: python, binary, byte, pickle, google-cloud-vision

Sooo... I need to read import an image dataset from a .pkl file. The images as stored as 'binary blobs'. Once this is done I need to convert them to a byte format so that I can run them through Google's Cloud Vision. I managed to open the file on a Linux VM (spent days trying to make it work on Windows...). But now I can't seem to transform this 'binary blob' to an actual image that I can use...

This that follows is one of the 'Binary-blobs':

> \xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x05\x03\x04\x04\x04\x03\x05\x04\x04\x04\x05\x05\x05\x06\x07\x0c\x08\x07\x07\x07\x07\x0f\x0b\x0b\t\x0c\x11\x0f\x12\x12\x11\x0f\x11\x11\x13\x16\x1c\x17\x13\x14\x1a\x15\x11\x11\x18!\x18\x1a\x1d\x1d\x1f\x1f\x1f\x13\x17"$"\x1e$\x1c\x1e\x1f\x1e\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\x05\x05\x05\x07\x06\x07\x0e\x08\x08\x0e\x1e\x14\x11\x14\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\x1e\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x00d\x00d\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x03\x04\x05\x07\x02\x08\x01\xff\xc4\x00A\x10\x00\x01\x03\x03\x02\x03\x05\x05\x04\x08\x03\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x00\x05\x11\x12!\x061A\x07\x13Qaq\x14"2\x81\x91R\xa1\xb1\xd1\x15#BSbr\x92\xc1\x083\xe1\x16Td\x82\xa2\xb2\xc2\xd2\xf0\xff\xc4\x00\x1a\x01\x00\x02\x03\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\xff\xc4\x00&\x11\x00\x02\x02\x02\x02\x01\x04\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x11\x03\x12\x04!2\x05\x131A"3Qaq\xc1\xff\xda\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xf43\x9cGmBTP\x99\x0ei;\xe9oN?\xab\x1e5\r\xce,\x8a2\x1b\x8f\x8f\'\x1fB~\xe0I\xac\xc7\xf4\xac}GP\xee\xd7\xd7RqO5s\x8c\xa2p\xfa\x0e\t\xeb\xd3\xa7\xddQT\x01\xec\x8e0u)\xfdTX\xe0\xe7\xed\xad\x7f\xf8\x8f\xc6\xa23\xc5\xb77[\n}-G$\x9c\xa5\xb6u\x11\xbf\x89^(H\#~\xf4Wbc*\x18\x05G\xd0T\x9d\x08%s\x88n+;K\x92\x07\x80\xee\xd1\xf8$\xd4I\x179\xee\x8c\trPr72V\xac\x8e\xa3\x03H\xaa\xb8\x8b\xef\x94t%c\x96\xea\xf4\xc7\xf6\xa9]\xca\xb1\xcf\x14\xbf\x11\x91\xc2\x1f2\x14\xe3\xf3\x15!\n\x18\xd0\xe2B\x809\xceA99\xe9\xcf\x1br\xa7C\xa9himIldgKH\x1b\x9c\xe3}>F\xbe\x96W\x9d\x814\x83\x0e\x1e\x98\xf54:\xfa\x04\x84TNr\xe3\xbb\xf88S\xf8\x1a`E\x88$*G\xb36^X\xc2\x9cP\xd4\xa5\x0f2w5$F_U\x01\xe9]{1\xea\xe55*v\x0f\xb28m\xa4\x9c\xa5\x96\xd2|\x92)k^FR\x900w\n\xf3\xdb\xa7\x87\xff\x00u\xa9&2z\xac\xd3K\x86\xc99*_\xd6\x95\x82HkX\xfbC\xebJ\xbb\xf6H\xff\x00g\xef\xa5N\xd0\x10d\xb2\x85\xa4\xa5hJ\x87\x81\x19\xa8v\xcbt4\xba\xfa\x84dd\xaf;\xa6\xa5;0\'wcIlu=\xde\xa0?\xa75\xdcyQ\x80I\xd6}\xf4\xea\x1e\xe1\xc9\x19>U\x06\xa8\x13D\x86\xa3\xb0\x9f\x85\x86\xc7\xa2E}rd(\xc4\xa5\xe9Q\xd9#\x98[\x89N+\xa6\xe44~\x14\xbc\xafF\x95\xf9V[qq\x98\x7f\xe2\x02\x13\x92\xa3\x1e\xeac$6\x9d\x00\x95\x12\x80\x81\xb7\xf3\n\x95\x00{q\xe3^\x17\xb6%K\x97y\x8c\x00\xfd\xde\\\xff\x00\xb4\x1a\xb1\xe1\xfb\xf5\xba\xfa\xb9M\xdb\xddR\xd5\x15IK\xc1H#\x1a\x86G\xa8 t\xac\xd7\xb7K\x0f\xe9\x05~\x97\x05\xd6\x85\xb6;$4p\x12\xb0\xb7T\x0e\xde#c\xd3\x91\xf2\xa2\xfe\xc9V\xdam\xd1\x9bKh\x0fH\x80\x87q\x90\n\xf4\xba\xe8\'\xcf\x19H\xfaSH\x03 \xd1\xaf\xa5\xae\xb95+C\xdd\x1a@\xf5W\xfaW\xc0\x89\x04n\x1bO\xd4\xd1B\xb2!A\xcdrRjQfGU7\xf2I\xfc\xe9\xbe\xe5\xfc\x9c\xb8\x07\x86\x13E\x05\x8ci5\xf1H4\xf1\x8e\xe9\xd8\xbcO\xfc\xa2\xb8\\u\xed\x97W\xe7\xca\x8a\x18\xc1F\xf4\xab\xa5G9\xff\x001\xcf\xea\xa5J\x80\x80\xf4\x88\xe8^\x95\xc8i*\xc6pV\x01\xa8\xed]\xad,\xac6\xfd\xce\x1bKY:B\xdfH\xcf\xa6\xf4%\xc4v[ZO\r\xb2\x98\xe9\xca\x9b\r,\x0f\x02\xea\xd4w\xe7\xfbT\xfd\xef\x84\xf8}\x9b\x03\xae\x0cFl\xabv\xdcg\xbc\x0bX\xc1\xf8\xc1\xd4\x90}\rS,\x8dWF\x9c\x1cxdmJj?\xd8]2\xf9j\x8b\x02D\xa4\xcc\x8e\xf9e\x95\xba\x1ai\xe4\x95\xb9\xa4\x13\x84\x8c\xeeO*\xf3\xefi<Qp\x9b\xc6V.$\xb6\xc6TY\x81\x1a\x98ecQ\xca]\xc2RG\\\xe0}kG\x8f\x1a\x0cH\x05\xe8\xf6\xcc\xb0\x10Ov\xd3`\x83\x8ceX\xf0\xaa\x89\xd1\xe3\xc8\xb7\xae\xe1\x1e1@\x0e\x02\x96\x82R\x922T>\xc9\xfb=\x08\xaa\xd7"*\xb7\xd9\x17\x85&\xfb\x18\xe2\xce+\xbc*\xec\xf7\x01q\xb1*\xd8\x0cT\x02J\x89\xc9C\xa3m\xc0\xea\xa5}(V\xc5\xc5\xfcV\x896T[\xdam\x9fem-2S\xb7|\x92\xbeD\x93\xcfS\x9azl\xad\xeb\xab\xc5\xcf\xbbK\xf1\x9eB\x18\x0b\x8c\xeb@\x95|J\x05*\x03\x7f%P\xdd\xb6[\xf1n0%5\x1d\xe4\xa8h\xf6rASo\x90\xbc\xfb\xa3\x1e\xf1\x07\x03byV\x98KdS(\xd3\xa3\xd8\xf1e\x85De\xc9)\xee\x9eSi.! \xa8%X\xdcds\xc1\xaf\xab\x9d\x10sp\xff\x00I\xac\x9dW\xeb\xd3\xa9\x0f<\xb9\xc9\xca\x06\xb0\xdcH\xed\x04\x9e\xbb\xac\x9eY5\xc2\xees\x0e\xff\x00\xa5.\xe9H;\xe2\xef\x19\xa1\x8cx$\x1fJ\xb1\x115qr\x84\xbd\x92\xe1?*b=\xda\x04\xb7\xd6\xc4W\x03\xee\xb6\xad.!\xb5%JA\xdfb3\x91\xc8\xd6P].\'*\x9b%\xc0\xe1\xd4\xbe\xfe\xfc\xa2\t\xc7@\x8f?\xc6\x83;4\xbe\xa2\x1fiV\xfb\x83\xebm-<\xea\xd0K\xc5^\xea\x1c\xd4Q\xb9\xe7\xb2\xd5\x92s\xb8\xa1\x88\xf4\x92\x9cWH\xef}\x00\xa6\xd6\xb7s\x81\x19y<\xb2\xa1Vj\x1e\x95\xc2\xd3@\x15y\x7f\xfd\xdb\xfe\xb1J\xa5\xaf\x1a\xb9\x8aT\x07g\x9d\xb8v\xe8\xa7\'\xb8]u\xe4\xfb"\xce\xbdh9iC\xa6\x9f\x1f>\xb5m\xc6\x97\xf7\x9f0\xa0\x07\x9c\x0c8\xca\x9eRT\x9d%J\xca\x80\xcf\xc8$\xfc\xe8C\x8b\xdf\x88\xab\xb4\x97l\xaew\xe8u)PTD\x1c-g)V\xc9\xf8\x8eS\x92\x7f\x88\x1eU\x0b\x8d\xfd\xa2\x15\xdd\xd8r\x13\xec\xcbk\xb8e\x01\xd5h\x05(oF\xa1\x93\x8c\x1c\r\xfc\xea\xaf\xb4Z\x9b]\x9ao\x07\xdc^\x91l\xd4\xf3\x8aWv\xa54\x08F\xa3\xa4h cl\xf35Y\xc4r\x96\xb7Z\xf6wV\x86\xdcB\xd5\xa3\x04\x05\x14\x927H\xce\xfb\x9f\x1ef\xaa\xb8mo=\xc3\x92#\xc2u\x87\xdf\xef\xc2\xc0C\x89prN\xc7\x04\xfd\x93NqR\x1a\x11a\t1\x08\xc2HR\x142\x12\xa3\x82q\xe5\x9c\xd6E\x92+"\x8b}\xdf\xf8]\xed\xbd6\xfe\n\x1e0XU\x86K\xeaC\x89\n\x8f\x801\x91\xf0\xa99\xe4:\xa9\xb1B\x10\xe396\r\xb9\xd8\xad\xddV\xa8z\x92\xa2\xcb!\xd4\x03\xab \'\x18)=z\xf3\xa3\x1b\xab\rK\xe1\xe9\xcd\xc7a([\xb1\x96\x90R7%#ZG\xf5!4#\xc2\x12&\xb2\n\xa2\xe1)\xfel\x15\xab\xcf=1\x8f\xa5j\xc6\xeeM\x15O\xe10\xc6\xdbn\x991*.p\xed\xd1\xd2\xe6r\\x90Z\xe6s\xcb \xf3\xa9\xdf\xec\xed\xf1 \xf7\\x1e\x87[>7#\x9c\xe4\x11\x90]\x1c\xb0:\xd4\xeb\x04\x9b\xd2\x82\x14\xb6S\xeb\xde\x8a3\x89&R\x18\xd5 6\xd8\xeaJ\xc6\x07\xce\xae+`\x1cN\r\xe2E\xc6m&\xd9\x11\x80\x00\x05\x0fOZ\xf6\xf0#R\x87\xd2\xa7Y\xfb?\xbb\xb7\x7f\x89:q\xb7)\x86\xa4\xa1\xd5\xb4\x1eR\xb2\x90\xe6\xa2\x91\xee\x0f\xd9%#~X\xa3\x88\xf2\x8a\xc9=\xf3*\xdbl8\rI\x05J\x01D\xe3\xe7J\xc2\x82\x85\xf1\x13\x83\x94T\xf9\xe5\x7f\xe9Q\xdd\xe2W\xc78\xcc\xf3\xfd\xe1\xfc\xaa\x8c\x8dm\xe9\xc9$\xd4EF\x92\xa5\x9fq%=\x0e\xaa[ \xd4\xbfs\x89U\xa8\xe5\x86\xb3\xea\xaf\xca\x95\x0e\x18\x13A:P\xde\t\xcf1\xf9R\xa3d\x1a\xb0O\x84xQ\xb4\xean\xee,\xf2\xdeI\x0bhEaLwi\x18\xe6R\x84\x13\xbe\xfb\xd4\xcb\xbf\x03\xda\xa5\xdc]\x9b>\x1a\x1d.\'b\xe4\xb7s\x8f\rEy\xdbo\xca\x85\xbb\x13{\x8a[\x9b)\xee+L\xd6\xca\xbd\xd6\xc4\xa64g\x97#\x80w\xcf\xddZ\x9d\xd1\xe6\x9dBFB\xb9\xe5#s\xf4\xaf9\xcf\xe4e\xc7\xfar\xec\xedqq\xc2~H\x02\x8d\xc2\xb6\x9b\x05\xf2\x05\xde,8\xd0\xe3\xc6R\xbb\xf5w\xb9\x01\x05$g\xc4\xfdz\xd3\x8e\xdf\xac\x12\xdf>\xd3>\xdc\xfbE\x00\'T\x94\x14\x92\x0e\xe3\x9f=\xc7\xd4U\xcf\x11\xb1\xed\xb69\xb1\x9amjS\x8c-\xb4\xe1?\xb4S\xb7\xe3X<>\xcfx\x9c@\x11\xdf\xb5\xa3)R\xca\x16d\xb6\x02\t-\xfb\xc4g\'d(c\x1dk>\x18C\x95\x1d\xf3OY"\xec\xd3\x96\x07\xac#i\x9b2\x11d\xee\xd4[\x11Z^p\x8d$\x13\xfc\xc0\r\xb1Y\x8f\x0b\xdb\xecmp\xf3\xb2\xaf+\xb6\x85\t%\xa6\xd9t\xadN#HH\'\x08P\xf7|\xce\xd9\xf5\xab\xd8\xf6\xc7\xadnG\x99.\xe1\x1e(\xee\x92\xca\xfb\xd3\xabR\xb6\xd9!\'*\xdcx\x8a\x03\xbfO\xb6\xce\x9a\x15c\x88\xfa\xc2U\x95<\xea\x80K\x8b\xe5\xafF0<rI\xe6yWO\xd3\xb1{r\x95I\xc9:0\xf3g\xb2W\x1a\xa0\x96\x1b\xfc,\x99\x05 \xda\xdbQ\xc6\x80\x95<J\xb27\xfd\xbcg;\x0c\x13Er/\xedL\xb5{\x1b\xb3\xad\xeb\x8a\xa1\xa1M\xa9\x0bI\xf7N\xc0\xef\x90A\x1fub\x12]\xd7#\x0f\xcb*t\xe59R}\xdc\xfa\x93\xfd\xaa\xd5\xa6\xe3\xdca\x08\x92\x90B\xdb\x05#\xed$\xa4d\x8d\xfai\x04\x8f\r$o\x91\x8e\xc3]Q\xcdO\xec\xd4b\xd9xq\xf7\x02]n\xd4\xa2@Q)S\xea\xe7\xe8\xbe~T\xec;\x7f\x03\xb2\xa5\xf7\xb7\x1b4t\x05\x94\xa4\xadr[\xd5\x83\xd3\xf5\xb8?,\xd6#\x0e\x12`\x97d\xba\x10\xea\xd2\xbe\xe9\x94\xa8\x1d%]TA\xe8\x91\xd3\xc4\x8f\x1a"\xb5\xda%\xcb\x82\xab\xbb\xf3\x13\x12:\x9c\r%\xe7}\xe7\x1e_\x82G]\xbd\x07N\x94\xb5\xa47+7+\x13\xdc5\t\xad\x10/\xf6\xb44\xea\x86\xe9\x91$\xa7Q\xd8\x0c\x97\x0e\x0f\x96\xd4R\xab\x04\xc7\x06K\xe0$\xef\x9dr\xc0\xfb\x97^k\xef$Dm\x0e\x99>\xd0\xceBT\xaciq\xbd@\x10q\x920A\x1dH\xe8y\xef\xd7\xb11up\xfe\xb1l\xbc\xd3\x89\x0f\x16\x8e2\x9ey\x03=S\x9c\x0eyI\x1c\x80\xa3T\xc3j= xGQ\xd4dn\x7f\xe2&\xff\x00\xefJ\xbc\x8d1\xe9q\xe4\xb8\x98\xb2_\xee\x14\xa2Q\xa9\xc5g\x19\xc6\xff\x00JT\xb5\r\xcd\xd3\xb4n\'k\x85\xd2\x92d=&c\xb9Sl\x82\x00\xdb\xaa\xb6\xe5\xf9P\x1c\x0e6\xe3\xcb\xa4\xadq\xa4\x16[plR\xd2p\x06\xfb\x02A5\x07\xb4G\x91z\xe3\x9b\xb4\x95\xac\xb4\xc4]\x0c\xb4\x14FU\x81\x8c\x01\xcc\x8c\xe7p6\xdb8\xa9\xc9\x9a\xda-o\xbf\r(em\xb4\x96\x90BA\xd1\x92\x06q\xbf\xf6\xf4\xac\x94L*:\x88JTI\xd23\xb0;\xd69\x7f\xbb\xcb\xb4]l\x97\x86\xd9.I\xee\x1bu\xd1\x9d9 \xe7\xa0\xdb4j\xcc~\xd28\x86\x0bw{Z\xac\xad"b{\xe0\xd2\xa5 8\x81\xd0(+\x18<\x8f\xce\xa8\xcf\xe9\xf3\xc9\x93li$h\xc1\xca\x84!Y;c\x9cqn\x89\x1a\xcb*\xed!\xe7\x14\xec6\xc9h\'\x01=\xe9\xd99\xdb\'r+8\x87%\x16\x9b\x1cb\x86\xca\x8b\xe7R\xcaH\x04\x0f\xef\xce\x9f\xed\x12\xdf\xc6\xb6\xb6\x98\x1cL\xb4\xf72\x96\xa2\x9e\xe6B\x1cmJN>\xc1 s\x1c\xff\x00\xb53eCW\x0bK\r-\xe0\xda\x19W\xbe\x9c|X\xf0\xf3\xae\x87\x1b\x03\xc3\r_f,\xd9\x16I\xda"\xdeZe\x99R\xdaM\xbc>\xa7\xd2\x90\xd2\x92\x7f\xcbVw8\x1c\xf2w\xa8I\x92\x98\xd3{\xc5\x92R\x9d\x01\xc0\x93\x9dx\x18_\xd7\xde\xfa\xd6\x85p\xe0\xde\xd0%[Z\x91i\xb3-\xf83\x06\xb6\xc3%\x05\xd2\x08\xe6Fu\x00EQ1\xd9?h2\x96\x84+\x87\xa40\x85\x9f\x89\xc5$c|x\xd6\x84\x8a[\x04\x8d\xc12\x8bL\x04+\xddq\xc5\x95\x1f\xe2\t\x00}\x13\xf7\xd6\xc7\x02\x0f\xb7vua\x99\x0c8\x18aNGx!$\x86\x9d9!\xc5\x14\xee9\x83\xb7Z\x9da\xff\x00\rw\x19\x11bJ\x9fxb2\x8a\xc9u\x86N\xa7\x02z\x0c\xa8\x04\x83\xf5\xc7\xaf(s\xb8;\xb4\xbe\xcf\xe7\xccj\xc1\x0ed\xebk\x99\xc9C\x01\xe4-?\xc4\xd8\xce\xff\x00")\xb8\xd8&\x8c\xedV\xa9p\x1d\x97"Dc\x19\x81\x19M,\xa8\x85\x07\x96\xb0\x92\x901\x9d\xf2\xa4\xab|r=E7n\x9c\xcc;\x9b\x8aqJ%\xd6R\xd2\x12\x06\xda\xb5s;\xed\xb6\xa1\x9f\xe2\xab\xfb\xb5\xa7\x8f\xaf\x0b\x06W\x0e]\nX\xd9,3m-6\xd9\xc7D% g\x1eT\xc5\xab\xb3\xee*zb$\8j\xecY\xcet\xa5\x85\xa4\x8f2H\xfc(I\xa0m\x1d\xa6\xc8\x1d\xc9\xf6d\'\x07\x18\xf7\xb6\xeb\xe3\xe7J\x8f[\xb2q[\xa8\nLYL\x004\xe8T3\xb6>T\xa8\xa6+A\xc5\xd6\xee\xf9\xb6\xbb\x011\xe27\x1fOq\xa5\rc\xdc\xd3\x8c}+\x01\xe0\xd7T\xf4\xc5\xc7t%m(\xee\x826?\r*T\x9f\x895\xe4m|\x15\xc2v\x8b\xfd\xa1\xd9\xb7\x148\xa5\x05)\x01\x08!)\xd2\x9c\x009g\x18\xf3\xabx]\x9a\xf0rfh\xfd\x12\x82\x9c\x8d\x89\xa5J\x88\xfc"\x12\xf2\x0c\xa6\xf6!\xd9\xec\xbb\x7ft\xf5\xa9}\xdaIP\tsI\xce<@\xcf\xdfR8?\x808*\xdfm~\xdb\x1b\x86m\x9d\xc8;\xa9\xc6C\x8bW\xaa\x95\x92iR\xab\x9aT\x0c)M\x8e\xdd\x05M\xa6+Jm\x1aBR\x80}\xd4\x8f/\n}QY\xd6\x1bP+H\xe5\xa8\xe6\x95*B\'C\xb6D+\xd9\x05\x18\xfb\'\x19\xf5\xa9.Ddr\n\xfa\xd2\xa5M\x00\xe3Q\x99\n\xc0O\xcf\xad\'\xe36H\xce\xaf\xad*T\xc4\xc6\xc4V1\xf0\xd2\xa5J\x81\x1f\xff\xd9

I've never worked with this type of data... but to my knowledge binary data should only  be 1s and 0s no? I'm just completely lost at this point... any help?

This is the code I used for opening the pickle file:

```
import pickle
f = open('fileName')
d = pickle.load(f)
```

'd' contains more 'stuff' that I need so I use a regex to extract the parts I need (one of which I showed at the beginning)

Comment: i think you have an error in the code because load does an different tasks. Did you know tha 'Load and loads are completly different. You should try: pickle.loads(***your command whatsoever***)

Comment: Just FYI, the first 'B' in 'BLOb' stands for 'binary'.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import pickle
f = "filename.pkl"
d = pickle.load(open(f, "rb"))
```

Using "rb" specifies to the open() method that you are reading bytes

Comment: Thx for the prompt response :) but it shows the same result as what I have; my problem is transforming a the string I posted to a byte format. So that i can feed it to the GCV

Comment: So to clarify, you have a python object that you want to turn into a binary object within python, and not save it to a file?

Comment: What I have is a .pkl file containing information about images and the images them-self. What I need to do is extract the 'binary-blob' and transform it to a byte format (since Google's Cloud Vision accepts only an image in byte format as input)

Comment: Well if you load the .pkl file into python as done above, it un-serializes it. To re-serialize it within python, you can use binaryD = pickle.dumps(d)

Comment: ok this kinda helped (formatting-wise); but I now I need to transform the 'binay-blob' (the string in the yellow box in my description) to a byte format.

Comment: I thought that was "d". Putting that string into pickle.dumps() should turn it into a byte format.